# I can't figure out why my iPhone App is running out of memory

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I am loading a bunch of data from a text file into CoreData. For some reason, every iteration through the for (line in lines) loop in the code below is allocating new memory. It works fine up until it can't allocate new memory. I can't see why it's not reusing the same memory for each iteration. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

`

-(IBAction)loadDataInThread {

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MileMarkers" ofType:@"csv"];
NSData *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *lines = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
status.hidden = FALSE;
// NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; 
NSFileManager *fileman = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
NSString *line;
NSNumberFormatter * myNumFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myNumFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; 
[myNumFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[myNumFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSManagedObject *newManagedObject;
NSArray *fields;
// NSLog(@"Loading Markers");
for (line in lines) {
    fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    self.stat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",[fields objectAtIndex:0],[fields objectAtIndex:1],[fields objectAtIndex:2],[fields objectAtIndex:3]];

    NSLog(stat);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MileMarkers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSNumber *f1 = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:[fields objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSNumber *f2 = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:[fields objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSNumber *f3 = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:[fields objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSNumber *f4 = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:[fields objectAtIndex:3]];

    [newManagedObject setValue:f1  forKey:@"ICWID"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:f2  forKey:@"MileMarker"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:f3 forKey:@"Latitude"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:f4 forKey:@"Longitude"];

    NSMutableArray *charts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *e = [fileman enumeratorAtPath:tileDirectory];
    NSString *path;
    int idx = 0;
    /*
    for (path in e) {
        NSString *pathFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/tilemapresource.xml",tileDirectory,[path stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
//      NSLog(@"parsing %@",pathFileName);

            BOOL checkFile = [self checkForLatLong:pathFileName latitude:f3 longitude:f4 ]; 
            if (checkFile) {
                NSLog(@"Match %d",idx);
                if (idx < 4){
                    self.counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",idx];
                    [charts insertObject:path atIndex:idx];
                    idx++;
                }
            }       

        }
    [path release];

    for (int lp=1; lp<[charts count]; lp++) {
        NSString *keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chart%d",lp+1];
        [newManagedObject setValue:[charts objectAtIndex:lp] forKey:keyName];
        }
    [charts release];
    */

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [error release];
}
[myNumFormatter release];

NSLog(@"Markers Loaded");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataLoaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[pool release];
```

}
`

Answer (score 7):

It's likely that you're producing lots of autoreleased objects inside this loop. Remember that autoreleased objects are still valid until the end of the whole event loop, at which point the autorelease pool is drained. Normally this process works more or less invisibly, but if you have loops that allocate lots of autoreleased objects, you *can* run out of heap.

You can alleviate this by creating and draining an inner autorelease pool within your loop, like so:

```
for (line in lines) {  
    NSAutoreleasePool * localPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ...
    [localPool release];
}
```

You should also explicitly release any created/retained objects that you don't need any more, like "charts" etc in the above.

Comment: This has certainly put me on the right track. I made a mistake when I commented out the  most innermost loop, and commented out the release of charts, so that wasn't the problem. I added a localPool inside the for (line in lines) section, and now that's working as I expect. Still having a problem with the inner loop that is commented out in my listing above, but now that I understand that autorelease objects can pile up in a tight loop, I should be able to figure it out. I'm assuming (hoping) that I can nest AutoReleasePools and create one in my inner loop too...

Comment: Yes, autorelease pools are nestable. There's a stack of them, and when an object is sent the `-autorelease` message, it gets added to whatever pool is on top of that stack. When that pool is released, it's popped off the stack and all of the objects in it get sent `-release`. The event loop happens to have one "surrounding" it, but it's not special; you can nest as many more as you like on the pool stack. Be careful about your object lifetimes as you do this, of course-- once you've released a pool, anything created during its lifetime might be gone.

Answer (score 3):

The "charts" mutable array is not being released.

This line,

```
NSMutableArray *charts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to release *charts* after you're done with it, like this:

```
[a1 release]
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic memory management problem.

Check this out...
[memory management](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/memory-management.html)

There are tons of other links out there as well...

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, always remember this tag line-
`When you use alloc or new or make a copy, you should definitely release it.`

That is you are managing the resources not the compiler. So it is your job to release them.

[More Information](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/)